# PThhHmmMssS date format to timespent

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I need to translate this format "PThhHmmMssS" (PT7H45M26.75S) to timestamp. Is there way to do this using moment.js

I looked for solutions in the forums but found nothing. I don't understand what standard this format is based on. It would be fantastic if you could help me unravel this mystery.

Comment: It is an [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), so a length of time(duration), not a moment in time(timestamp) so parsing it as a date makes no sense. That being said moment can handle durations per this duplicate: [Convert ISO 8601 duration with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626417/13762301)

Comment: But [moment is outdated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), instead look at [datefns](https://date-fns.org/). Duplicate: [Convert ISO8601 duration to seconds in typescript using date-fns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288316/convert-iso8601-duration-to-seconds-in-typescript-using-date-fns)

Comment: Timestamp or time spent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format "PThhHmmMssS" is one of the [ISO 8601 duration formats](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/duration.html), an international standard for representing dates, times, and durations.

- "P" indicates the start of the duration.
- "T" separates the date portion (if present) from the time portion.
- "hh" represents hours.
- "mm" represents minutes.
- "ss" represents seconds.
- "S" represents milliseconds.

"PT" indicates that it's a time duration.
"7H" represents 7 hours.
"45M" represents 45 minutes.
"26.75S" represents 26.75 seconds, so you have 7 hours, 45 minutes, 26.75 seconds.

Note the different outputs in the examples below. Luxon returns ISO and the other example a JS date object

Luxon has support

```js
const parseAndAddDuration = (durationString) => {
  try {
    const { Duration, DateTime } = luxon;
    const duration = Duration.fromISO(durationString);
    const currentDate = DateTime.local();
    const newDate = currentDate.plus(duration);
    return newDate.toISO();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Invalid duration format');
  }
};

// Example usage:
const durationString = "PT7H45M26.75S";
const newDate = parseAndAddDuration(durationString);
console.log("New Date:", newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.1.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

---

There is a [tinyduration package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyduration) that was updated recently (June 2023)

---

**vanilla JS parsing**

You do not need moment which is deprecated and no longer maintained) or any other library unless you have more uses for it. Just a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZIu1Jj/1) and some date manipulation

```js
const regex = /P(?:T(\d+)H)?(\d+)M(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)S)?/;

function parseAndAddDurationToCurrentDate(durationString) {
  const match = regex.exec(durationString);

  const hours = match[1] ? parseInt(match[1]) : 0;
  const minutes = match[2] ? parseInt(match[2]) : 0; // Use ternary operator for minutes
  const seconds = match[3] ? parseFloat(match[3]) : 0; // Handle optional seconds
  const totalSeconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;


  const currentDate = new Date();

  currentDate.setSeconds(currentDate.getSeconds() + totalSeconds)
  return currentDate.toISOString();
}


// Example usage:
let durationString = "PT7H45M26.75S";
let newDate = parseAndAddDurationToCurrentDate(durationString);

console.log("New Date:", newDate);


durationString = "PT16H30M";
newDate = parseAndAddDurationToCurrentDate(durationString);

console.log("New Date:", newDate);
```

Comment: just found the duplicate: [Convert ISO 8601 duration with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934089/convert-iso-8601-duration-with-javascript) apparently moment does handle durations

Comment: I believed the "moment can't handle it" and did not look. It seems you need a plugin for it though and it is [many years old](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

Comment: also with [datefns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288316/convert-iso8601-duration-to-seconds-in-typescript-using-date-fns) which is more modern anyway since moment itself recommends not using it in new projects

Comment: I added Luxon too

Comment: @pilchard getting a 404 on the datefns iso package in the link you posted

Comment: [Here is one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-duration) from an [old issue](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/284)

Comment: @Yogi the dupe is not moment specific and has 10 answers many of them vanilla. I also note that moment is outdated in my comment on the question.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm afraid I didn't vet my dupes very well, but the point is a little looking yields vanilla js dupes and pointers on library solutions. 'date-fns' handles formatting to an ISO duration but not parsing one which is a shame.

Comment: Found this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/64372730/295783